# How to connect to MS Access using c# class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I used to connect to Microsoft Access using Windows form as code below:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source=C:/Users/titi/Desktop/db2.mdb");

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from tblBook", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

It works fine, but now I create another class of C# , that is not the Window form. I just want to compare some data in MS Access with Data that I select with SQL Server. But when I do that, I got error like:

> Error  1   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration C:\A\A\SynchronizeData.cs   12  17  AutoSync

Could any one tell me, how to connect to MS Access like in Windows form using the class in C#?

Comment: Sorry. I mean, how to connect to database (ms. access).

Comment: Can you provide all the code for SynchorizeData.cs? Also stick your initialization of OleDbConnection in the class constructor or within the Load method.

Comment: This is all my code in the SynchorizeData.cs, what do you mean `stick your initialization` ?

Answer (score 2):

The error means that you have a typo in your file `C:\A\A\SynchronizeData.cs`, probably around line 12. Fix the typo, and your code should work fine.

Comment: This is my file that I am coding.

Comment: @titi: Yes, that's good, because that means that you can fix the typo.

Comment: No, I mean ` C:\A\A\SynchronizeData.cs`  is my class, but I don't know why it error at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
//on Form Load set your connection string
Conn = "..Your Connection String";
MyClass.MyCon = Conn;

//on event handler call your class
string conSTR = MyClass.MyCon

//this is your class
public class MyClass
{
  public static string iMyCon = "";

  public static string MyCon
  {
    get { return iMyCon; }
    set { iMyCon = value; }
  }
}
```